# How to configure a cron.d crontab file for root

Tags: linux, bash, cron, crontab

What's the procedure for installing a cron.d crontab file to be run as root?

I have a script I want root to run every 10 minutes, so I installed the file `/etc/cron.d/mycron`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/10 * * * *   root    /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

then rebooted cron and I ensured I could execute `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh` and that it ran correctly.

However, as far as I can tell, it never actually gets called since the script writes to a log file and the log file never gets created. Is there some step I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered all `/etc/cron.d` files need to have permissions set to 600, otherwise cron reports an "INSECURE" MODE error.